# i want to extract error log when using update_column in circle ci rspec parallel execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, circleci

right now
this code snippet of ses updating code is fail in parallel excution.

target code

```rb
class A_class
 def
  update_column(:bounced_at, bounce['timestamp'].to_datetime)
 end
end
```

test code

```rb
let!(:a_class) do
  create(
   :a_class,
   blahblah
)
end

context '#5' do
  a_class.apply_ses_notification!(json['Message'])
end
```

i want to extract in these steps to look into whats happening
and i couldnt succeed to 1) step .

embedding into

`rails_helper.rb`
or
`environments/test.rb`

**i wrote in these two code but not working...**

1. extract log file
   inserting

   ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new("log/sql_error.log")
   ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 0
2. buld in circle ci yml to let them uploading correctly

```
  - store_artifacts 
   path log/sql_error.log
   destination error-logs
```

Do somebody know how to deal with it?

```
      - image: hoge/my-mysql:latest (i injected my.conf) 
        environment:
          TZ: Asia/Tokyo
        command:
          mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

      parallelism: 16

      # run tests!
      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            shopt -s globstar
            TEST_FILES="$(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)"
            bundle exec rspec --format progress \
                            --format RspecJunitFormatter \
                            --out /tmp/test-results/rspec.xml \
                            --format progress \
                            --profile 10 \
                            $TEST_FILES
```

Comment: Your method does not have a name. Nor it it a class method. You are not calling the method correctly in your test code. I don't see how this is even working locally.