# it never been shown up at sql error log file like ERROR 1064 error

Tags: mysql

im stuck everytime on this issue

mysql version 5.7

i want to put out every single error in the mysql file.
like `ERROR 1064`

```
mysql> select * aaafrom hoge;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'aaafrom hoge' at line 1
```

i setup `my.cnf`

```
log-error=/var/log/mysqld2.log
```

and verbose to top level

```
| log_error                | /var/log/mysqld2.log  |
| log_error_verbosity      | 3                     |
```

[image]

but ERROR 1064 (42000) doesnt come out to my logging file..

FYI
this kind of error can be shown . but i want to more error logging

```
mysqladmin -u root debug
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

```
 tail -3 /var/log/mysqld2.log
2023-04-19T05:43:08.845972Z 8 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-04-19T05:43:16.630962Z 9 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-04-19T05:43:23.911286Z 10 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: You want to log every syntax error (which is what a 1064 error is) that every developer makes?

Comment: @P.Salmon hi thaks for the comment.

to be honest my final goal is this issue , i want to extract some unknown error that happens at CI pipeline. to do that , i need to put as much errors  as possible to log file to see whats happening .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76050549/i-want-to-extract-error-log-when-using-update-column-in-circle-ci-rspec-paralell